# Map projection with longitude values 0-360

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to plot a world map with longitude coordinates 0, 360. When i do so, either longitude points start from mid-map, or the projection of the map is thrown off. Here is an example:

```
ggplot() + 
      geom_polygon(data = world_map, aes(x=long, y = lat, group=group)) + 
      coord_fixed(1.3) + coord_equal(xlim = c(0, 360), ylim = c(-90, 90))
```

[image]

I would like for the longitude to read 0 to 360 with the full map projection.

Comment: maybe simply  `geom_polygon(data = world_map, aes(x=long+180, y = lat, group=group))` ?

Comment: agree with @LoBu. longitude values go from -180:180 so you will have to adjust them if you want them on a 0:360 scale by adding 180

Comment: While this does project the map on a 360 degree scale, it places the prime meridian west of Alaska rather than in west Africa @LoBu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "world2" map from the maps package, which has range [0,360]:
    ggplot() + 
      geom_polygon(data = fortify(maps::map("world2",plot=FALSE,fill=TRUE)), aes(x=long, y = lat, group=group)) + 
      coord_fixed(1.3) + coord_equal(xlim = c(0, 360), ylim = c(-90, 90))

Alternatively, if you want the freedom to have any shift of the map, maps v3.2.0 (just uploaded to CRAN) will allow you to do

```
myworld = maps::map(wrap=c(0,360), plot=FALSE, fill=TRUE)
    ggplot() + 
      geom_polygon(data = fortify(maps::map("world2",plot=FALSE,fill=TRUE)), aes(x=long, y = lat, group=group)) + 
      coord_fixed(1.3) + coord_equal(xlim = c(0, 360), ylim = c(-90, 90))
```

[image]